# webpack libraryTarget merge properties to an existing variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

Is it possible to configure webpack's `libraryTarget` to **merge** exported properties to an existing object variable, instead of just assigning it and overriding?

For example, given this exported module:

```js
{ a: function(){}, b: function(){} }
```

And given this global variable:

```js
window.myLib = { someProp: "some value" }
```

The end result i would like is:

```js
window.myLib = { someProp: "some value", a: function(){}, b: function(){} }
```

I've read about `libraryTarget: 'assign'` but it seems to override the variable and not merge the properties (unless i am missing something)

If there is no such configuration, is it possible to create a custom function / plugin that can handle the `libraryTarget` assignment? i searched for such option but couldn't find one, I feel like i am missing something here.

I would need this for webpack V3 or V4

Comment: Something like this feature request https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11571?

Comment: @chenxsan Spot on, not sure how i missed that issue. So i guess its not supported out of the box yet, i wonder if i can create a plugin that can alter the native behavior some how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `libraryTarget: "assign-properties"` to merge properties recursively.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849394)